# contemptuous of vs contemptuous to

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following sentences is grammatically right?

I am contemptuous of my History teacher.

I am contemptuous to my History teacher.

Comment: Both are valid: in the second example you are contemptuous towards the teacher, ie directly to them.  The first example is more general and could include when discussing the teacher with your friends for example.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemptuous

> feeling or showing deep hatred or disapproval : feeling or showing contempt

So "contemptuous of" is the feeling; "contemptuous to" is the showing.

Answer (score 0):

The wording I'd recommend would be:

"I am contemptuous of..."
"I feel contempt for..."

Max is right, in that you can also be contemptuous **to** someone which would suggest that you're being actively and openly scornful.